# VS (2019) Cannot find form design view after saving project

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2019

After I pressed save as (to make a backup file), it closed my original file and opened the backup. I removed it from the project by right clicking, and then it closed. I then tried to open back the original file but I could not find the form file. I opened every file and none opened the form file. Is there a way to get it back? There is no syntax errors in the (main) code, so I assume its still there somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

If your target framework is .Net framework, you can try to open designer view via the steps below:

1.Open the solution explorer (View -> Solution Explorer, or Ctrl+W, S).

2.Select one of the mentioned classes like form or user control.

3.Right-click it and select View Designer (or simply Shift+F7). That will move you to the designer view.

And the .NET Core Windows Forms designer is available with the Visual Studio 16.5 Preview 1.

More details you can refer to this [blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-core-windows-forms-designer-preview-1/).

Best Regards,
Daniel Zhang